# Why do I have to start a transaction using PDO and then commit it before I can delete data from MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When I ran this piece of code

```
<?php

include '../bin/config.php';
connect();

if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])){

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM noteline WHERE Nid = ?");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $outcome = $stmt->execute();

    if ($outcome){

        echo 'it was successfully deleted';
        header("Location: ../noteline");
    }else {

        echo 'it was not successful due to something';
    }
}


?>
```

it echoed "it was successfully deleted" but nothing was deleted from my database...
but when I started a transaction by modified this code like this:

```
<?php

include '../bin/config.php';
connect();

if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])){

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM noteline WHERE Nid = ?");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $conn->beginTransaction();
    $outcome = $stmt->execute();

    if ($outcome){

        $conn->commit();
        echo 'it was successfully deleted';
        header("Location: ../noteline");
    }else {

        echo 'it was not successful due to something';
    }
}


?>
```

My data was finally deleted from my MySQL database!
I want to know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the PDO connection is operating with auto-commit mode disabled.  Look into the `connect()` function to ensure that you don't disable this mode.

(Also, I see you're using a global variable to store the connection object.  Avoid global variables where possible.)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your server might have autocommit turned off?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

> By default, MySQL runs with autocommit mode enabled. This means that
>   as soon as you execute a statement that updates (modifies) a table,
>   MySQL stores the update on disk to make it permanent.

There might be a line in your code somewhere that sends

```
SET autocommit=0;
```

to your server.